# View under the statusbar and a 20px white space

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I don´t know what I did, but just recently the hole view is displaced 20px to the top. The effect is, that my UIToolbar is under the statusbar and at the button is a white space. I set the statusbar in the plist to not hidden. But my second view, which is loaded by pressing a button will be displayed properly.

Any idea? Thanks for your help!

Here is how the ViewController will be load in the AppDelegate:

```
    BenutzerdatenViewController *Benutzer = [[BenutzerdatenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    Benutzer.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [window addSubview: Benutzer.view];
```

I think there is no more important code to share.

**UPDATE:** Until now I just have a manual fix: I moved all ui-elements 20px down in the userinterface and made the window of the AppDelegate black, because my view is black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the nib file. Open it up in IB, and check out the dimensions pane in the inspector. In my experience it often had 460px height in there, depending on my simulated UI elements settings (first tab). Hope this helps.